# Enum to specify ComparisonMode

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Is there an enumeration in the .NET Framework that specifies values for comparison like, `Equal`, `GreatherThan`, `LessThanOrEqual` etc.. I tried looking in the namespace `System.ComponentModel` but did not find anything relevant.

I want to use this enum in a class library that has no association (assembly references) to any frontend technology (WinForms, WPF,etc.)

I now that I can easily define this enum on my own, but I want to reuse it if it exists already.

Comment: I doubt it since the general convention is -1, 0, 1. When you define your enum make sure to use these values :)

Comment: You *might* be able to use the CodeDom's [`CodeBinaryOperatorType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codebinaryoperatortype(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration - but it does cover almost all binary operators, not just comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CodeBinaryOperatorType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codebinaryoperatortype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  enum. Not sure if that fits you, this is what closer I can find.

Btw I found it by searching in reflector by preloading the .Net framework base class libraries.

Comment: not bad, it contains what I need, but also provides values that are (currently) not relevant for me.

Comment: @Jehof I guess there is nothing for comparison as you asked. I searched in reflector can't find any.

Comment: thanks i appreciate your help. I use this enumeration and create my own if it does not match my requirements

Comment: Looks pretty close to what you wanted to me, maybe you need to clarify on what "etc." is

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No.

Perhaps you should just follow the conventions MS has used ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx

i.e. Return int where...

Less than 0  - x is less than y.

0 - x equals y.

Greater than 0 - x is greater than y.

It's either that or use the System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorType or create your own Enum

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for something to return as a *result* of a comparison, but rather for a way to *specify* the type of comparison to perform (but, maybe I'm just reading too much into their use of the word `Mode` in the question). So the `int` convention doesn't really apply here.